# Python Pandas Not Recognizing JSON File

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonp

I'm trying to load JSON data in Pandas in order to do some analysis.

Here is an example of the data I'm analyzing.

http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/game/football/fbs/2013/08/31/wyoming-nebraska/field.json

I have tried the following:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

json_data = pd.read_json('jsonv3.json')
```

and also

```
import json
import pandas
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('jsonv3.json')

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)

json_data.close()
```

The resulting errors are as follows:

1) ValueError: Expected object or value

2) ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I don't really know why the JSON file is not being recognized.

I've confirmed on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ That it is valid JSON. I don't really know how to debug the issue. I haven't been able to find anything. Is the error potentially because of the JSON spacing format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not JSON, it is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Note that the JSON "content" is wrapped in a "function call" `callbackWrapper(...)`.  From the wikipedia article: "The response to a JSONP request is not JSON and is not parsed as JSON".

If you've saved the JSONP response in the file `jsonv3.json`, you could strip off the function call wrapper and process the content with something like this:

```
import json

with open('jsonv3.json', 'r') as f:
    response = f.read()

start = response.find('(')
end = response.rfind(')')
json_content = response[start+1:end]
data = json.loads(json_content)
```